# Play and Pause with onclick on the same Img

Tags: javascript, html, audio, onclick

The following script is playing a soundfile when i click on a img (onclick). How do i pause it by clicking on the same img? I´ve tried audio.pause(), but it won´t work.

```
function play(){
var audio = document.getElementById("myaudio"); 
audio.style.display="block";
audio.play();
}

<a href="#" onclick="play()"><img src="Bilder/play2.png"></a>
```

Comment: what error you can see when using `audio.pause()`?

Comment: There is no error when i do F12 in the browser...

Comment: maybe the better question is: can i do onclick="play(); pause()" ??

Comment: Can you make some fiddle and share it?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8z4x2eha/2/

Comment: I think you have mark any answer which fixed your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rename your function to `audioHandler()` for example which will handle whether to play or pause your audio.

Create a boolean to remember if your audio was playing or was on pause.

```
//initial status: audio is not playing
var status = false;
var audio = document.getElementById("myaudio");

function audioHandler(){
  if(status == false || audio.paused){
    audio.play();
    status = true;
  }else{
    audio.pause();
    status = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: works great so far... I can click 1xplay and 1xpause, then it wont work again. is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

Check the `media.paused` property of your [*HTMLMediaElement*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement)

```
function play_pause(media) {
    if (media.paused) {
        media.play();
    else {
        media.pause();
    }
}
```

Use this in the handler on the element you want to control the action

```
var elm = document.getElementById('play_button'),
    audio =  document.getElementById('myaudio');
elm.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    play_pause(audio);
});
```