# Play/Pause on onclick, but only once?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, onclick

The following code plays and stops an audio file, but only once. (1 x play, 1 x pause). Is there a way to play/pause regularly?

```
function audioHandler(){
 var audio = document.getElementById("myaudio"); 
 if(status == false){
 audio.style.display="block";
 audio.play();
 status = true;
 }
 else {
 audio.style.display="none";
 audio.pause();
 status = false;
 }
}
```

It´s not that important, but i also want to change the play to a pause icon and backwards...

```
<a href="#" onclick="audioHandler()"><img src="play.png"></a>
```

Comment: Have you check my answer which i given in your previous quesion?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28740265/play-and-pause-with-onclick-on-the-same-img/28740494#28740494

Comment: thank you so much, it works as well, i´m just trying to get better in general, with different options... thx

Comment: Ok. you have set your variable global. which i write in my first question answer. Hope it works well. all the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the global variable `status`, since you are using it as a global variable(the window object has a property called status), the value assigned to it will be converted to string.

So when you apply `status = false`, the real value assigned will be `status = 'false';` which will always be truthy, ie `'false' == false` will be false so your `if` block will never get executed again!!!

So just rename the variable `status` to something else then it should work

```
var aStatus = false;
function audioHandler() {
    var audio = document.getElementById("myaudio");
    var audioimg = document.getElementById("myaudioimg");
    if (aStatus == false) {
        audio.style.display = "block";
        audio.play();
        aStatus = true;
        audioimg.src = "pause.png"
    } else {
        audio.style.display = "none";
        audio.pause();
        aStatus = false;
        audioimg.src = "play.png"
    }
}
```

then

```
<a href="#" onclick="audioHandler()"><img id="myaudioimg" src="play.png" /></a>
```

Comment: thank you so much, works perfectly. Maybe you got a thought on my second question? :)

Comment: thx... i just realized, that the file starts on the second click, so now it wont match with the img change. It´s like: 1st click nothing, 2nd click start, 3rd click stop - but then the img is still on play? i´m confused

Comment: i just figured to swap the img, so that works. But the player wont start at the first click...

Comment: thank you sir... works fine. appreciate the help. enjoy your day